# How to host mongo db in ASp.net web application

Tags: asp.net, mongodb

i just want to know that it is possible to keep mongodb in App_Data folder in asp.net application.If possible how i can access that for my application.

Answer (score 0):

Check http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/

Ensure mongodb command (commandline or service) has dbpath option set correctly and that you can run the DB server from within the specified mongodb installation folder

To use the DB, copy the dll files into bin directory or GAC and ensure you are using correct instance

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Community+Projects

Comment: you can use App_Data as data folder (dbpath)